# SQL Code it says can't have aggregated function in (MAX(AVG(winRate)))

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Teams_ID
FROM Players P, Heros H
WHERE P.Heros_ID = H.ID
GROUP BY Teams_ID
HAVING AVG(winRate)=(
    SELECT MAX(AVG(winRate))
    FROM Players P, Heros H
    WHERE P.Heros_ID = H.ID
    GROUP BY Teams_ID
);
```

Comment: you can have an anggregate of aggregate function: MAX(AVG(... NOT PERMITTED

Comment: Please add a tag with your DBMS

Comment: Please add the exact error message

Answer (score 2):

You have to write it as two separate `SELECT` clauses:

```
SELECT Teams_ID
FROM Players P, Heros H
WHERE P.Heros_ID = H.ID
GROUP BY Teams_ID
HAVING AVG(winRate)=(
    SELECT MAX(avgWinRate)
    FROM (SELECT AVG(winRate) as avgWinRate
          FROM Players P, Heros H
          WHERE P.Heros_ID = H.ID
          GROUP BY Teams_ID
    ) as t
);
```

This makes it clear that the `MAX` *isn't* meant to be `GROUP BY`ing `Teams_ID`.

You may also wish to a) look into explicit join syntax and b) if your RDBMS supports it, look at windowed aggregates to avoid having to duplicate the query.

This is what I'd prefer, if your DB supports it:

```
select *
from (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AvgWinRate desc) rn
    from (
        SELECT Teams_ID,AVG(winRate) OVER (PARTITION BY Teams_ID)  as AvgWinRate
        FROM Players P inner join Heros H
        ON P.Heros_ID = H.ID
        ) t
    ) u
where rn = 1
```

This also more naturally extends/composes with larger queries.

Comment: Indeed, this should solve the problem (=cannot nest aggregate functions).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should write the query using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax and qualify *all* column references.

Then you can use `ORDER BY` and some limiting clause to do what you want:

```
SELECT ?.Teams_ID
FROM Players P JOIN
     Heros H
     ON P.Heros_ID = H.ID
GROUP BY ?.Teams_ID
HAVING AVG(?.winRate) = (SELECT AVG(?.winRate)
                         FROM Players P JOIN
                              Heros H
                              ON P.Heros_ID = H.ID
                         GROUP BY ?.Teams_ID
                         ORDER BY AVG(?.winRate) DESC
                         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
                        );
```

The `?` is for the alias to specify where the column comes from.  Not all databases support `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW`, but all have some mechanism for limiting the result set.

If you only want one row even in the event of ties, then you can do:

```
SELECT ?.Teams_ID
FROM Players P JOIN
     Heros H
     ON P.Heros_ID = H.ID
GROUP BY ?.Teams_ID
ORDER BY AVG(?.winRate) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```